# Как ввести одно целое число с консоли

Tags: haskell

Придумал себе задачу на базовые элементы языка - "перевести температуру из градусов цельсия в фаренгейты", запнулся на этапе ввода целого числа:

```
-- Ask temperature in Celsius then convert to Fahrenheit

temperatureFahrenheit temperatureCelsius = 32 + temperatureCelsius * 9 / 5

main = do
    putStrLn "What is temperature in Celsius?"
    c <- getLine
    let temperatureCelsius = (read c :: Int)
    result <- temperatureFahrenheit temperatureCelsius
    putStrLn ("It's " ++ result ++ " in Fahrenheit")
```

Получаю ошибку компиляции (под рукой нет установленного haskell, это вывод с [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/4bVCFI)):

> ```
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prog.hs, prog.o )
>
> prog.hs:8:30: error:
>     • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
>       Expected type: Int
>         Actual type: String
>     • In the expression: c :: Int
>       In an equation for ‘temperatureCelsius’:
>           temperatureCelsius = c :: Int
>       In the expression:
>         do putStrLn "What temperature in Celsius?"
>            c <- getLine
>            let temperatureCelsius = ...
>            result <- temperatureFahrenheit temperatureCelsius
>            ....
>   |
> 8 |     let temperatureCelsius = c :: Int
>   |                              ^
>
> prog.hs:9:15: error:
>     • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO [Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
>     • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>         result <- temperatureFahrenheit temperatureCelsius
>       In the expression:
>         do putStrLn "What temperature in Celsius?"
>            c <- getLine
>            let temperatureCelsius = ...
>            result <- temperatureFahrenheit temperatureCelsius
>            ....
>       In an equation for ‘main’:
>           main
>             = do putStrLn "What temperature in Celsius?"
>                  c <- getLine
>                  let temperatureCelsius = ...
>                  ....
>   |
> 9 |     result <- temperatureFahrenheit temperatureCelsius
>   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Что не так? Мне нужно взять строку, получить на выходе Int - так это по крайней мере мне видится в терминах скажем c#.

Что пытался делать:

- похожий пример есть на en so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42214447/5752652
- видел [примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173532/5752652) на использование Parsec, но мне показалось это из пушки по воробьям - я осваиваю базу, потому хотелось бы без сторонних библиотек, тем более мне не нужны пока числа через пробел - тут с одним бы разобраться
- читал про устройство типов в IO https://habr.com/en/post/153383/#hell-difficulty-part но пока в голове не укладывается как это использовать
- читал про readLn описание https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn покрутил так и эдак разные варианты кода - тож не заработало
- ну и просто всякие буквари читал типа http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters и https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/haskell/ на предмет общего синтаксиса

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки три

- над `temperatureCelsius` производится операция деления, она доступна только для дробных типов (представителей класса `Fractional`), но не для `Int`. Либо меняйте тип на `Double`, либо используйте целочисленное деление `div` или `quot`, либо явно приводите типы.
- `temperatureFahrenheit temperatureCelsius` не IO-действие, здесь нужно использовать `let result = ...` вместо `result <- ...`
- операция `++` конкатенирует строки а не числа со строками. используйте `show` для получения строкового представления числа.

Comment: А я правильно понял, что тип `IO String` - это не то же самое что тип `String` и нужно ещё одно преобразование?

Comment: @AK да, это разные типы. Если не сильно углубляться, делайте `x <- (значение типа типа IO String)`. Тогда `x` будет типа `String`

Answer (score 2):

Так, варианты в целых числах (допустим, перевод цельсий -> кельвин).

Через getLine:

```
-- Ask temperature in Celsius then convert to Kelvin

temperatureKelvin temperatureCelsius = temperatureCelsius + 273

main = do
    putStrLn "What is temperature in Celsius?"
    c <- getLine
    let temperatureCelsius = (read c :: Int)
    let result = temperatureKelvin temperatureCelsius
    putStrLn ("It's " ++ show result ++ " in Kelvin")
```

Через readLn:

```
-- Ask temperature in Celsius then convert to Kelvin

temperatureKelvin temperatureCelsius = temperatureCelsius + 273

main = do
    putStrLn "What is temperature in Celsius?"
    c <- readLn
    let result = temperatureKelvin c
    putStrLn ("It's " ++ show result ++ " in Kelvin")
```

И допустим надо ввести два числа, одно целое, одно рациональное. Скажем, [расчёт ИМТ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0):

```
-- Ask mass and height, then calculate BMI (body mass index)
-- Result for mass = 77 and height = 1.70 is 26.643598615916957

bmi mass height = mass / (height * height)

main = do  
    putStrLn ("Enter your mass in kilos")
    mass <- readLn
    putStrLn ("Enter your height in meters")
    h <- getLine
    let height = (read h :: Double)
    let result = bmi mass height
    putStrLn ("Your body mass index is " ++ show result)
```

Спасибо @extrn за указание на ошибки: когда их сразу больше одной -- непросто понять, почему никак к ответу не получается придти.